# How to store config information for a ASP.NET site not in Web.Config

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, csv, web

I need to store a file pairing colours and images for use in my JavaScript. I would have liked to use a simple CSV file and Papa Parse, but PP requires either text or a `File` object as input, and I can find no way of opening a `File` object, nor of reading the text from the CSV file. Surely my code should be allowed to read files that reside under the web site, not randomly among the file system?

My alternative is to have the end user, non-technical, edit a JSON file that is parsed by my code.

Am I wrong, or is this the case? Then maybe I should build an editor for the JSON file that simplifies the data editing for the end user.

All the file has to store is colour/image name pairs.

Comment: Why does your title include ASP.NET but you don't have it as a tag?  The question doesn't seem to be about ASP.NET either.

Comment: It's about an ASP.NET site, not ASP.NET itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like this? Are you getting an error? Sorry, I cannot leave comments yet.

```
StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/data.txt"), true);
    _testData.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text); // Write the file.
    _testData.Flush();
    _testData.Close(); // Close the instance of StreamWriter.
    _testData.Dispose(); // Dispose from memory.
```

Comment: I need to do this in the JavaScript parts of the site.

Comment: JavaScript runs client side. Am I missing something? You want to edit a text file client side? One cannot access the files other than a cookie client side (security). Can your solution involve sending data to the client and editing it with Papa Parse based and csv data stored in a cookie or html 5 local storage? If the text file is server side, you have to perform an ajax call server side to perform the file edits.

Comment: So far I've decided just to store the info in a json file, with .js extension. That's welcome on the site.